# python keeps running previous modules instead of the one i wanna run?

Tags: python

I'm trying to run a code right but python keeps running previous ones so like I've tried to replace the code that it's trying to run with my current one but it still doesn't work?

I've also tried to re-download my graphics file heaps of times but that still doesn't work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code then ?

Comment: With only that information it's impossible to answer your question. What exactly did you do?

Comment: You may be picking up a different version than you think. If your module is named "foo" for instance, after importing print `foo.__file__` to see if its the one you want. You could also try adding a `print(__file__, "version xxx")` (where you change xxx each time you change the file) to the top of the module so you get immediate version confirmation when you load it.

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede - this may not be code dependent so much as where the edited .py file is placed. I'm trying to think of the usual reasons why the wrong file would be imported.

Comment: Are you having the problems in a shell? If you edit and run `import mymodule` it doesn't actually reload your module. The running code can `import imp` and then call `imp.reload(mymodule)` to attempt to reload the module.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing all `*.pyc` files as well as any `__pycache__/` directories as these may contain previous versions, causing your problem.